# AngularJS - Range slider doesn't work in ng-repeat (plugin)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use this plugin in my project to have multiple range slider within ng-repeat. http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/

The plugin works fine when there is single slider , but when i try to put multiple slider in ng-repeat it doesn't work.

Not sure is there anything wrong with my codes or the plugin doesn't support that.

Is there anyway i can make it work?

Here is the demo plnkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/9H7WF44X7zCWaw91jDyr?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller='PriceCtrl'>

  {{position}}
  <div>
      <slider floor="10" ceiling="60" ng-model-low="position.minAge" ng-model-high="position.maxAge"></slider>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
    <slider floor="10" ceiling="60" ng-model-low="item.minPrice" ng-model-high="item.maxPrice"></slider>
  </div>
</body>

app.controller('PriceCtrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.items = [{name: "item 1", minPrice: 10,
                  maxPrice: 50},
                  {name: "item 2", minPrice: 5,
                  maxPrice: 40},
                  {name: "item 3", minPrice: 15,
                  maxPrice: 30}];

  $scope.lower_price_bound = 0;
  $scope.upper_price_bound = 50;

  $scope.position = {
    name: 'Potato Master',
    minAge: 25,
    maxAge: 40
  };

});
```

Comment: This seems to be a know issue https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider/issues/12

Comment: oops where gone the amatuere fix comment :S.. why deleted? it looks good :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rg-slider`](http://manar007.github.io/rg-slider/)
It's allows you to use multiple sliders in one page.